asking about N N relations
In ERD,i have A and B entity which has N-N relation name as C.Can C has another relation to an entity as D?I think it is possible but I didn't get any answer on internet
the question is all of my problem,nothing to explain here

Yes, this is possible: C can be a ternary relationship between three entities.
However, this is tricky for the cardinalities: in this case, you can no longer say that A and B have an N:N relationship, because the cardinality is to be understood with the pair of two other entities.
If you want to keep your binary relationship, another way is to make C an associative entity: it is the relationship between A and C but at the same tile it is an entity that could have relationships with D.
